# What causes a newly installed application not to launch when run the first time?

Tags: kubuntu

Sometimes when I install a new application and I run it just after it's installed, I get the bouncing cursor for a while and a button in the task manager bar, and then it just disappears and the application does not run.

What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

This is really not possible to answer as a blanket statement. For some reason, the application fails to load. This could be because it is missing a dependency, hasn't been configured yet, or for some other reason.

You would need to include the name and log files from an application to see why it isn't starting. You may also be able to see why it isn't starting by attempting to start it from the command line.

Comment: How can it be missing dependency ? Doesn't a deb package install all packages it depends on? How does starting it from command line be different ? Or do you mean start it as super user ?

Comment: Well you didn't specify what it was or where you got it from. If you didn't get it from the repos, then missing dependencies are a possibility as it could be bad packaging. Starting it from the command line would likely print to the terminal the reason it fails to start.

Comment: Yes I install the applications from the repo and sometimes even running them from command line does not display any error and makes the same behavior.However, in some cases running them as super user the first time solves the problem and allow them to be run normally afterwards. I do not understand why either.

Comment: Examples : Google Picasa 3 and even Gimp yesterday did the same thing.

Comment: At that point, I would check syslog and see if anything is printed there.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. System Log did not show anything about Picasa but it did show the error : 07/09/11 09:57:27 PM hp1060 kernel [13026.196378] gimp[9004]: segfault at 50 ip 00007f6e726d5d1c sp 00007fff9cd00ed0 error 4 in libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.4[7f6e724e6000+436000]
with gimp. Gimp runs fine as su and it display the same error in terminal when run as normal user. What does this error mean and how can I know why Picasa fails to launch?